# Trending our answer rate to 100% and our answer rank to 1st

Tags: discussion, unanswered-questions, statistics

At time of writing (August 18, 2015) we have:

- [262 questions with no upvoted or accepted answers](https://travel.stackexchange.com/unanswered/tagged/?tab=newest)
- [219 questions with no answers](https://travel.stackexchange.com/unanswered/tagged/?tab=noanswers)
- a [98%ish answer rate, which puts us at 29th overall](http://stackexchange.com/sites#percentanswered) on the network

I'd like to track this with the goal of getting the answer rate up to 100% (with rounding, at least), and our rank site-wide at 1st for answering, and as such will occasionally update below with updated stats.  Feel free to do this as well.

Comment: In this one, the answer is **you cannot compare things that do not exist**, please read http://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/49527/online-comparison-of-currency-exchange-services-in-germany#comment106991_49527  And yet there's upvotes on the question.  Now what?

Comment: @GayotFow write an answer about how it doesn't exist, simple. We've done it for other questions (eg can you go as a tourist to the moon)

Comment: Absolutely, questions are legitimate even if there is no answer because there is no way for for the asker to know this in advance. It depends on the way the question is worded though, For example: *Can I drive from Halifax to Greenland?* vs *How long does it take to drive from Halifax to Greenland?*. The first question can be answered with a *no*, the other is impossible.

Comment: As usual, I love the spirit behind this effort. Keep in mind though, an answered rate of 98% is... kinda great! As pointed out elsewhere, you're always going to get a few oddball questions that are valid but just really difficult to answer well or not great and yet not quite delete-worthy either.

Comment: @Pops indeed, and we favour accuracy in answers over just answering.  We'd been on top of questions with only about 40 unanswered back in April and it slipped out to 250+, so this is just an effort to reign that back in - it was annoying to see the easy ones we'd missed, and dupes and so on.  But certainly we still have questions open since before then that we haven't been able to answer, because they're hard or rare :)

Comment: Can we repeat this event for 2016?

Comment: @JonathanReez been thinking we should, but waiting for the June event to finish first :)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Update answer below with the following:

- [date of update](https://www.google.com.au/search?q=current%20time%20utc) **(Date)**
- [# questions with no upvoted or accepted answers](https://travel.stackexchange.com/unanswered/tagged/?tab=newest) **(NoVotes)**
- [# questions with no answers](https://travel.stackexchange.com/unanswered/tagged/?tab=noanswers) **(NoAnswers)**
- [% answer rate](http://stackexchange.com/sites#percentanswered) on the network **(%Answered)**
- [rank for answer rate](http://stackexchange.com/sites#percentanswered) on the network **(Rank)**

```
+----------------------+---------+-----------+-----------+------+
| Date                 | NoVotes | NoAnswers | %Answered | Rank |
+----------------------+---------+-----------+-----------+------+
| October 3rd, 2015    |  50     |  47       | 100%      |  7th | 
| October 1st, 2015    |  45     |  43       | 100%      |  9th |
| September 30th, 2015 |  39     |  39       | 100%      |  8th |
| September 29th, 2015 |  43     |  43       | 100%      |  8th |
| September 28th, 2015 |  45     |  44       | 100%      | 10th |
| September 27th, 2015 |  48     |  44       | 100%      |  7th |
| September 26th, 2015 |  47     |  47       | 100%      |  9th |
| September 25th, 2015 |  50     |  48       | 100%      |  8th |
| September 24th, 2015 |  53     |  50       | 100%      |  8th |
| September 23rd, 2015 |  55     |  54       | 100%      |  9th |
| September 22nd, 2015 |  51     |  51       | 100%      |  9th |
| September 21st, 2015 |  53     |  53       | 100%      |  7th |
| September 20th, 2015 |  51     |  51       | 100%      |  8th |
| September 19th, 2015 |  51     |  51       | 100%      |  9th |
| September 18th, 2015 |  53     |  52       | 100%      |  9th |
| September 17th, 2015 |  55     |  55       | 100%      |  9th |
| September 16th, 2015 |  67     |  66       | 99%       | 10th |
| September 15th, 2015 |  75     |  74       | 99%       | 14th |
| September 14th, 2015 |  79     |  76       | 99%       | 13th |
| September 13th, 2015 |  80     |  78       | 99%       | 14th |
| September 12th, 2015 |  81     |  79       | 99%       | 14th |
| September 11th, 2015 |  84     |  82       | 99%       | 15th |
| September 10th, 2015 |  90     |  87       | 99%       | 16th |
| September 9th, 2015  |  94     |  91       | 99%       | 16th |
| September 8th, 2015  |  99     |  94       | 99%       | 16th |
| September 7th, 2015  | 105     | 100       | 99%       | 17th |
| September 6th, 2015  | 111     | 105       | 99%       | 17th |
| September 5th, 2015  | 113     | 107       | 99%       | 17th |
| September 4th, 2015  | 116     | 111       | 99%       | 18th |
| September 3rd, 2015  | 115     | 107       | 99%       | 18th |
| September 2nd, 2015  | 116     | 107       | 99%       | 17th |
| September 1st, 2015  | 124     | 114       | 99%       | 17th |
| August 31st, 2015    | 127     | 119       | 99%       | 16th |
| August 30th, 2015    | 146     | 132       | 99%       | 19th |
| August 29th, 2015    | 147     | 137       | 99%       | 19th |
| August 28th, 2015    | 145     | 141       | 99%       | 20th |
| August 27th, 2015    | 153     | 149       | 99%       | 22nd |
| August 26th, 2015    | 164     | 158       | 99%       | 23rd |
| August 25th, 2015    | 172     | 162       | 99%       | 24th |
| August 24th, 2015    | 182     | 172       | 99%       | 23rd |
| August 23rd, 2015    | 189     | 175       | 99%       | 25th |
| August 22nd, 2015    | 192     | 178       | 99%       | 24th |
| August 21st, 2015    | 197     | 184       | 99%       | 25th |
| August 20th, 2015    | 210     | 198       | 98%       | 26th |
| August 19th, 2015    | 242     | 221       | 98%       | 28th |
| August 18th, 2015    | 262     | 219       | 98%       | 29th |
+----------------------+---------+-----------+-----------+------+
```

Comment: What about the questions with answers but unvoted?

Comment: @Karlson that's the NoVotes column.

Comment: That has everything.  Answers with no votes and no answers.  All I am looking for is answers with no votes.

Comment: @Karlson ah. I don't know how to separate those out. I guess it'd be the difference - so today, 164-158 =8.

Comment: Reformatted table using http://www.sensefulsolutions.com/2010/10/format-text-as-table.html