# The October Challenge - Here's your chance to finally answer expat questions!

Tags: discussion, competitions, expat-questions

As we've now got our [unanswered down to <40 questions](https://travel.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3367/trending-our-answer-rate-to-100-and-our-answer-rank-to-1st), doing pretty well, how about we spend a month helping out [Expats](https://expatriates.stackexchange.com/)?

The winner will be the one with the most answers with upvotes on previously unanswered questions.

The catch: You can't answer a new question until a previous one has **TWO** upvotes. Then you can include it in your list below, and answer a new one.

Thoughts? It'll give some of us more exposure to expats, and help them with their beta.

STATS for Expats:

Update answer below with the following:

- [date of update](https://www.google.com.au/search?q=current+time+utc) **(Date)**
- [# questions with no upvoted or accepted answers](https://expatriates.stackexchange.com/unanswered/tagged/?tab=newest) **(NoVotes)**
- [# questions with no answers](https://expatriates.stackexchange.com/unanswered/tagged/?tab=noanswers) **(NoAnswers)**
- [% answer rate](http://stackexchange.com/sites#percentanswered) on the network **(%Answered)**
- [rank for answer rate](http://stackexchange.com/sites#percentanswered) on the network **(Rank)**

```
+----------------------+---------+-----------+-----------+------+
| Date                 | NoVotes | NoAnswers | %Answered | Rank |
+----------------------+---------+-----------+-----------+------+
| October 14th, 2015   |  178    |  175      |    88%    | 88th |
| October 12th, 2015   |  178    |  175      |    88%    | 88th |
| October 9th, 2015    |  177    |  174      |    88%    | 88th |
| October 8th, 2015    |  184    |  176      |    87%    | 92nd |
| October 7th, 2015    |  187    |  176      |    87%    | 93rd |
| October 6th, 2015    |  191    |  179      |    87%    | 94th |
| October 3rd, 2015    |  181    |  170      |    87%    | 92nd |
| October 2nd, 2015    |  181    |  169      |    87%    | 94th |
| October 1st, 2015    |  185    |  173      |    87%    | 95th |
| September 30th, 2015 |  184    |  172      |    87%    | 94th |
| September 29th, 2015 |  187    |  173      |    87%    | 93rd |
+----------------------+---------+-----------+-----------+------+
```

Comment: Only 2 questions on Czech Republic on the website, but I'll try to join.

Comment: I don't know jack about expatting. But I'll try.

Comment: @JoErNanO feel free to create an entry for yourself below.

Comment: You can't answer a new question until a previous one has uproots. <= uproots? You mean you need to wait for an upvote?

Comment: @chx - uproots = upvotes, stupid autocorrect :/

Comment: If you see on that I can answer, please ping.

Comment: How do you calculate the Rank without manual counting? Is there a browser script? I got tired updating the Travel.SE rank :)

Comment: @JonathanReez manual counting :( It's easier as we answer more questions, and we get closer to the top ;)

Comment: Also if anyone feels enthralled by the idea, going through the unanswered questions and looking for potential close-vote questions helps as well.

Comment: Do only answers on previously unanswered questions count?

Comment: @drat good point, will update

Comment: What's the formula for the rank? I could create a sede query for it.

Comment: @JoErNanO presumably just ordered by %answered. I don't think it's particularly fancy.

Comment: @JonathanReez [The list view kinda makes it easier to count the ranks.](http://stackexchange.com/sites?view=list#percentanswered) Don't know if I can make a SEDE query for this since it's kinda of a cross-site information.

Comment: Any more recent stats updates on this? Or did the competition fizzle out?

Answer (score 2):

### JoErNanO

Answers with upvotes on expats: **2**.

1. https://expatriates.stackexchange.com/questions/7075/car-ownership-detail-uk
2. https://expatriates.stackexchange.com/questions/7081/can-an-eu-citizen-move-to-another-eu-country-to-work-remotely-at-a-job-not-in-th

Comment: @MarkMayo For some weird reason the url's aren't automagically converted into question titles.

Comment: yeah, same for me - I'm just forcing the links (edit mine to have a look)

Answer (score 2):

### Drat

Answers with upvotes on expats: **3**.

1. [What can I do with my pension when leaving Norway?](https://expatriates.stackexchange.com/a/7039/107)
2. [Portuguese citizenship card application in India?](https://expatriates.stackexchange.com/questions/5942/portuguese-citizenship-card-application-in-india/7049#7049)
3. [Studying in the Netherlands for one year; Must my children go to school?](https://expatriates.stackexchange.com/a/7113/107)

Answer (score 1):

### Mark Mayo

Answers with upvotes on expats: **6**.

1. [After employer change, do I have to go to US Embassy for visa stamping again?](https://expatriates.stackexchange.com/questions/7035/after-employer-change-do-i-have-to-go-to-us-embassy-for-visa-stamping-again)
2. [How to fill in the Canada Express Entry Profile when I am married but separated and my spouse is not coming with me?](https://expatriates.stackexchange.com/questions/6415/how-to-fill-in-the-canada-express-entry-profile-when-i-am-married-but-separated)
3. [Is there a penalty if I withdraw a J1 visa in any stage of the process?](https://expatriates.stackexchange.com/questions/5929/is-there-a-penalty-if-i-withdraw-a-j1-visa-in-any-stage-of-the-process)
4. [Where to find non-anecdotal and up-to-date information regarding the cost of living in other countries?](https://expatriates.stackexchange.com/questions/7071/where-to-find-non-anecdotal-and-up-to-date-information-regarding-the-cost-of-liv)
5. [Applying for an UK Ancestry Visa, can't select that visa type on Teleperformance website](https://expatriates.stackexchange.com/questions/5835/applying-for-an-uk-ancestry-visa-cant-select-that-visa-type-on-teleperformance)
6. [Do real estate agents in Melbourne actively help you find a rental?](https://expatriates.stackexchange.com/questions/7065/do-real-estate-agents-in-melbourne-actively-help-you-find-a-rental/7114#7114)

Answer (score 1):

### blackbird57

Answers with upvotes on expats: **1**.

1. [Can I apply for a work permit while entering Canada, after submitting an application online?](https://expatriates.stackexchange.com/questions/6214/can-i-apply-for-a-work-permit-while-entering-canada-after-submitting-an-applica/7047#7047)

Answer (score 1):

### JonathanReez

Answers with upvotes on expats: **0**.

*answers to be listed from October 1st*